# call api in canAcitvate - Angular

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular-router, angular8, angular-router-guards

I'm trying to work with Auth guards in angular. I have a httpcall that sets a true/false value based on a response back from an HTTP call. The problems are: 1) httpClients return an observable 2) the httpClient subscription needs to happened before the Authorized method gets called, that way the hasSessionFlag is already set.

**DUAL SERVICE .TS**

```
hasSession() {
    return this.http.get<{}>('API CALL', {
      withCredentials: true,
      observe: 'response'
    }).subscribe((res=>{
      if(res.status === 200) {
        this.hasSessionFlag = true;
      } else {
        this.hasSessionFlag = false
      }
    }));
  }

//Check if all the logical conditions of the user sessions pass*
  isAuthorized(): boolean {
      if (this.hasSessionFlag) {
        this.authService.login();
      } else {
        this.dualLoginRedirect();
      }
  }

  canActivate(): boolean {
    return this.isAuthorized();
  }
```

ROUTER.TS

```
   {
      canActivate: [DualLogonService],
      path: 'test',
      component: TestPageComponent
    }
```

Comment: You are doing a lot of imperative style of coding, you can quite easily achieve by applying a reactive style of coding. There could be a better way to achieve the same if you could share "this.isUserLoggedIn()" and "this.isInternal()" code or give an idea what it does. BTW, canActivate return type could be an Observable<boolean>, so you can also compose your httpClient observable and project it to return boolean and finally return that observable from canActivate.

Comment: @user2216584 I updated my questions. I simplyfied it, but then how can the auth guard will subcribe to the canActivate?

Comment: please see my answer. Notice, my assumptions. If my assumption is not correct let me know the correct assumption. I will update the code accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your latest code, I think this is what you want to do:

If API returns status is 200 then you want to call "`this.authService.login();`" otherwise "`this.dualLoginRedirect();`"

[As per your code at the time of writing this answer - Your `isAuthorized()` method does not return boolean instead it returns undefined. It must return a boolean or an observable of boolean or promise. I am assuming that in case of status is 200 then it will return `true` otherwise it will return `false`].  With this assumption, you can have only `canActive()` method like this:

```
canActive(): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.http.get<{}>('API CALL', {
              withCredentials: true,
              observe: 'response'
            })
            .pipe(
              map(res => {
                if(res.status === 200) {
                  //OR DO here whaterevr you want to do
                  this.authService.login();
                  //return true will render the associated component
                  //i.e. pass the guard
                  return true;
                } else {
                  this.dualLoginRedirect();
                  //return false will fail the guard.
                  return false;
                }
              })
            );
  }
```

Your guard service will **automatically subscribe** to the returned observable of `canActivate()` method.

Also, notice that in this approach there is no class members are declared. Although if your guard needs it just declare them and use them as per your requirements.

Comment: very cool, question....so what I understood is that my auth guard service is smart enough to subscribe to my observable when i got to "x" route that has the canActive?

Comment: @PatricioVargas Yes! You are absolutely correct, angular guard's canActiavte() should return Observable<boolean | UrlTree> | Promise<boolean | UrlTree> | boolean | UrlTree inorder to pass/fail the guard. If it returns an Observable then it automatically subscribes to unwrap the boolean. As a developer, you need not do anything. Refer: https://angular.io/api/router/CanActivate

Comment: this works, but I have a questions. When activate returns false, it takes me to the page B, then takes me back to the page A, where I was. I shouldn't take me to page B if it's false. Is it because it's waiting on the observable to complete?

Comment: @PatricioVargas - I am not aware of what `this.authService.login()` and `this.dualLoginRedirect();` does. But guard has only one **RESPONSIBILITY** - Can user route to the requested url? If your guard logic returns false it means you must route the user somewhere [i.e. A page which informs the user that you are not allowed to access this page OR Login Page]. If true then your component will be rendered in the respective router-outlet. From your comment, it appears that `this.dualLoginRedirect();` the method is having logic which navigates the app to page B. continue in next comment....

Comment: Returning false means request path cannot be accessed. It is **NOT** related to if it was waiting on the observable to complete. It is related to what `this.dualLoginRedirect();` method does.

Comment: I removed ```this.dualLoginRedirect();``` because i thought that was the issue and actually don't need it anymore, but keeps giving me the issue. Let me check if commenting ```this.authService.login() ``` works

Answer (score 1):

Instead of doing a subscribe on your http call, you can do a tap and set the value for hasSessionFlag....so do this..

```
hasSession() {
    return this.http.get<{}>('API CALL', {
      withCredentials: true,
      observe: 'response'
    }).pipe(
      tap(res=>{
      if(res.status === 200) {
        this.hasSessionFlag = true;
      } else {
        this.hasSessionFlag = false
      }
    }))
  .switchMap(res=>{
      if(this.hasSessionFlag)return this.authService.login();
      else return this.dualLoginRedirect();
}));
  }
```

```
isAuthorized(): boolean {
      if (this.hasSessionFlag) {
        this.authService.login();
      } else {
        this.dualLoginRedirect();
      }
  }
```

assuming your authService.login() and dualLoginRedirect() are observables

Comment: of course...you'll have to import the tap operator from rxjs/operators

Comment: Question, how will the hasSession() will be triggered? or where do I need to call it?